# Crear un programa en javaFX creando objetos en 3D y luego poder seleccionarlos mediante una lista circular doblemente enlazada

Tags: java, javafx

Lo que debo hacer es crear en un proyecto de java objetos en 3D con las librerias de javaFX y despues de creados los objetos crear una lista circular doblemente enlazada que me permita buscar entre los diferentes objetos que fueron creados

Todavia no logro aprender a programar debidamente y esto es realmente malo debido a que mi carrera unversitaria requiere mucho de programacion

Comment: Hola buen día, este sitio es para problemas específicos de programación, ¿puedes detallar más el error que tienes?

Comment: Bienvenido para entender que clases de preguntas son las que se contestan en el sitio te invito a leer [ask].

Answer (score -1):

**Documentación de mínima escena en 3d y demo**

[image: scene 3d javafx]

La documentación es para java8 , pero los objetos de javafx para 3d no están deprecados : [getting started javafx 3d](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm)

Para hacer una mínima escena 3d se necesita  `Scene` o `Subscene`  con `Zbuffer enabled`  y el antialiasing es opcional . la escena debe tener una cámara en `Subscene.setCamara()`  o `Scene.setCamara()` , cámara del tipo `PerspectiveCamera` y , a lo menos ,  un objeto del tipo `Shape3D` .`PerspectiveCamera` y `Shape3D` deben ser hijos de un objeto `Group` , que es un sistema de coordenadas donde -y es arriba y +z es propfundidad .
El tópico de gráficos 3d es complicado , pero dejo un demo en una sola clase con **bidirectional bindings** e interacción entre la subscena 3d los botones del mouse y el grupo de botones . Este código está escrito en javafx 17.0.2 y jre17 coretto

```
public class App extends Application {
    
    private RadioButton cylinderButton;
    private RadioButton sphereButton;
    private RadioButton cubeButton;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
//3d part
        Shape3D sphere = new Sphere(25);
        sphere.setTranslateX(50);
        
        sphere.pickOnBoundsProperty().addListener((c) -> {
            boolean test = sphere.isPickOnBounds();
            double scale = (test) ? (1.2) : (1.0);
            sphere.setScaleX(scale);
            sphere.setScaleZ(scale);
            sphere.setScaleY(scale);
            
        });
        
        sphere.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE));
        Shape3D cube = new Box(35, 35, 35);
        cube.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.YELLOW));
        cube.setTranslateX(-50);
        cube.pickOnBoundsProperty().addListener((c) -> {
            boolean test = cube.isPickOnBounds();
            double scale = (test) ? (1.2) : (1.0);
            cube.setScaleX(scale);
            cube.setScaleZ(scale);
            cube.setScaleY(scale);
        });
        
        Shape3D cylinder = new Cylinder(15, 40, 24);
        cylinder.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.RED));
        cylinder.pickOnBoundsProperty().addListener((c) -> {
            boolean test = cylinder.isPickOnBounds();
            double scale = (test) ? (1.2) : (1.0);
            cylinder.setScaleX(scale);
            cylinder.setScaleZ(scale);
            cylinder.setScaleY(scale);
        });
        
        PerspectiveCamera perspectiveCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        perspectiveCamera.setTranslateZ(-300);
        perspectiveCamera.setFarClip(500);
        perspectiveCamera.setNearClip(1.5);
        
        Group group3d = new Group(perspectiveCamera, sphere, cube, cylinder);
        SubScene subScene = new SubScene(group3d, 300, 300, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        subScene.setCamera(perspectiveCamera);
        subScene.setFill(Color.PALEVIOLETRED);
        subScene.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            PickResult pick = e.getPickResult();
            
            Node test = pick.getIntersectedNode();
            sphere.setPickOnBounds(test.equals(sphere));
            cube.setPickOnBounds(test.equals(cube));
            cylinder.setPickOnBounds(test.equals(cylinder));
            
        });

        // radio buttons 
        cylinderButton = new RadioButton("cylinder");
        sphereButton = new RadioButton("sphere");
        cubeButton = new RadioButton("cube");

        // bidirectional bindings
        cylinderButton.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(cylinder.pickOnBoundsProperty());
        sphereButton.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(sphere.pickOnBoundsProperty());
        cubeButton.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(cube.pickOnBoundsProperty());
        // group buttons
        ToggleGroup shapes = new ToggleGroup();
        
        shapes.getToggles().addAll(cylinderButton, sphereButton, cubeButton);
        shapes.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(e -> {
            if (shapes.getSelectedToggle() != null) {
                Toggle selectedToggle = shapes.getSelectedToggle();
                sphere.setPickOnBounds(selectedToggle.equals(sphereButton));
                cube.setPickOnBounds(selectedToggle.equals(cubeButton));
                cylinder.setPickOnBounds(selectedToggle.equals(cylinderButton));
            }
            
        });
        cylinderButton.setSelected(true);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(sphereButton, cylinderButton, cubeButton);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        vBox.setSpacing(20);
        
        HBox hBox = new HBox(subScene, vBox);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.setSpacing(20);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Aquí no estamos para hacerle los deberes a quien no quiere hacerlos. Si se está quejando de que no sabe programar, debe aprender. Venir aquí, copiar y pegar el código no le va a servir de nada, ni a él, ni al resto de la comunidad. Su pregunta es literalmente el enunciado del ejercicio además de un párrafo explicando que no sabe programar... no hay ninguna demostración de esfuerzo o intento de resolverlo. Responder a este tipo de preguntas solo sirve para favorecer la aparición de más y más preguntas de este tipo, convirtiendo SO en una copia del rincón del vago para programación.

Comment: Por no hablar de que tu respuesta realmente no responde a su pregunta, y cito: *crear una lista circular doblemente enlazada que me permita buscar entre los diferentes objetos que fueron creados*.

Comment: Cuanta toxicidad . No respondi toda la pregunta .solo la de crear un programa en 3d ¿NO? Además una buena forma de aprender es copiar . No solo le respondo a él .también pueden ver el código otras personas.es un app funcional en una sola clase de un topico bastante dificil . Ademas esta casia al dia en javafx 17 .no habian muchas preguntas respecto a javafx 3d .si alguien hace la busqueda , daria con un buen punto de entrada.

Comment: Es la única entrada si busca 'javafx 3d' la única a la fecha

Comment: No es toxicidad, es adhesión a las reglas. La pregunta tiene múltiples preguntas en una, no aporta código y demuestra 0 esfuerzo. No es una buena pregunta. Si quieres enseñar algo sobre javafx 3d nadie te impide crear tú mismo una **buena** pregunta y auto responderla de manera **completa**. Pero esta pregunta es de una calidad pésima y su título no resulta ni siquiera de ayuda a quien tenga otra duda similar puesto que no menciona un problema concreto que pueda tener alguien. Las reglas del sitio están para seguirlas, de esa manera **TODOS** podemos aprender, no solo el autor aprobar.